# Store a collection of objects in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am working on a developing a utility class for storing data in SharedPreferences. Till now, I was able to make a generic function to store and retrieve String, int and boolean. Is there a generic way to store and retrieve a collection of objects?

Comment: Could you please provide you generic function?

Comment: Hint: how about storing JSON directly as String...!!!

Comment: using TinyDB you  can store Generic any type of objects https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

Comment: Yeah, I have gone through that. When I try to get the list from getListObject(String key, Class<?> mClass), it returns a list of objects. How should I cast this list to list of my custom objects? @SuryaBondada

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way but two indirect ways:

**1. Use GSON.**

```
public static boolean saveObjectToPrefs(String prefKey, Object object, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(object);
        editor.putString(prefKey, json);
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
    }
}
```

The generic here should implement **Serializable** interface.

To retrieve object create a method like this:

```
public static <T> T getObjectFromPrefs(String prefKey, Class<T> type, Context context) {
    String json = getSharedPreferences(context).getString(prefKey, null);
    if (json != null) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            T result = gson.fromJson(json, type);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and you can call this method like for collections:

```
PrefUtils.getObjectFromPrefsByType(PREF_KEY_USERS, new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>() {
    }.getType(), context);
```

for normal objects you can do:

```
PrefUtils.getObjectFromPrefsByType(PREF_KEY_USER, User.class, context);
```

**2. Write a custom Serializer and Deserializer**

I usually prefer this method as I don't have to include a library for it.

Here is the custom serializer/deserializer implemetation:

```
public class ObjectSerializer {


public static String serialize(Serializable obj){
    if (obj == null) return "";
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serialObj);
        objStream.writeObject(obj);
        objStream.close();
        return encodeBytes(serialObj.toByteArray());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

public static Object deserialize(String str)  {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) return null;
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeBytes(str));
        ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(serialObj);
        return objStream.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder strBuf = new StringBuilder();
    for (Byte b: bytes) {
        strBuf.append((char) (((b >> 4) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
        strBuf.append((char) (((b) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
    }
    return strBuf.toString();
}

public static byte[] decodeBytes(String str) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=2) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        bytes[i/2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
        c = str.charAt(i+1);
        bytes[i/2] += (c - 'a');
    }
    return bytes;
    }
}
```

Now, inside PrefUtils.java you can have method like:

```
public static void saveUser(Context context, User user) {
    getSharedPreferences(context)
                        .edit()
                        .putString(PREF_KEY_USER, ObjectSerializer.serialize(user))
                        .apply();
}
```

To retrieve the object you can use following method:

```
public static User getUser(Context context) {
    String serializedUser = getSharedPreferences(context).getString(PREF_KEY_USER, "");
    return ((User) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(serializedUser));
}
```

Again User class has to be Serializable. Also, don't forgot explicit casting as ObjectSerializer.deserialize(String str) method returns an object of type **Object** and not the class you serialized. Also, take care of null values.

Comment: How can we use this generic to store and retrieve a list of objects?@Embydextrous

Comment: Are you talking about GSON method:

To save call:
PrefUtils.saveObjectToPrefs(PREF_KEY_USERS, users, context);   //users is ArrayList<User> and User is serializable.

Comment: To retrieve call:

PrefUtils.getObjectFromPrefsByType(PREF_KEY_USER, new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>() {
    }.getType(), context);

Comment: Could we make it more general. like having a single method to store the list of object (could be any custom object) and method to get the list of objects of specific type.

Comment: @Karan.. I think we have single method here only. One to saveObject other to retrieve object. The only thing differs is Type and Preference Key.
In case of second method you have to use different methods however. There is no way to do it using single method.

Comment: I suspected it to be so, anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a generic way to store and retrieve a collection of objects?

No, as of now, there is no generic way. You can use the following methods:

- putBoolean(String key, boolean value)
- putFloat(String key, float value)
- putInt(String key, int value)
- putLong(String key, long value)
- putString(String key, String value)
- putStringSet(String key, Set values)

That's all you can do with `SharedPreferences`. If you want to store anything generic, you can try to serialize your object and put it as a String to SharedPreferences. [About Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I've spend a lot of time playing with that question. Since I work with an iPhone guy how can save anyObjects (what is that??)  :)

I have settled on 2 solutions. If im storing a cache that have a short term usage, I wrap an abitrary object as a Parceable with Parceler (https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler).

If I need persistent data that the app uses to save user actions, I wrap any abitrary object with GSON, and save it to the disk. That way I can still update the app with more fields, and still use the data that comes from the GSON object, since it handles null value fields. (https://github.com/google/gson)